# Как в PhpStorm открыть 2 ветки одного и того же проекта в 2х окнах?

Tags: phpstorm

Нужно открыть один и тот же проект в 2х окнах, что бы в одном окне работать с одной веткой Git, а в другом окне в другой ветке.

Если я пробую открыть уже открытый проект, то ничего не происходит.

Подскажите возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: А как вы собрались открывать 2 ветки? При переключении на другую ветку файлы же могут быть другими, и те файлы что открыты были в 1 окне могут не существовать в другой ветке.

Comment: в отдельное директорию нельзя что ли ветку вторую выгрзузить?

Comment: Да, я уже как раз сделал отдельную директорию. Правда, тупит шторм почему-то, когда оба проекта открыты.

Comment: странно - почему бы ему тупить при удвоении размера проекта? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). Одной командой можно вынести вету в отдельную директорию: `git worktree add <path> [<branch>]`. Однако стоит иметь в виду, что два открытых проекта требуют примерно в два раза больше ресурсов. Поэтому для ускорения работы IDE лучше увеличить количество доступной ей памяти (*Help | Diganostics | Change memory settings*).